# 2D array length in java when decleared with int[][] a = new int[0][N]

Tags: java, arrays, width, 2d

Can someone please explain to me why this does not work:

```
int[][] array = new int[0][5];
int n = array[0].length;
```

while this does work:

```
int[][] array = new int[5][5];
int n = array[0].length;
```

I was doing some unit test to find the width and height of a NxN array when I ran into this problem.

Comment: Just to be clear, this isn't a _problem_ :p

Answer (score 4):

You are making a zero-sized array that will hold an array of size 5

```
int[][] array = new int[0][5];
```

You must at least give dimension of 1

```
int[][] array = new int[1][5];
```

which becomes basically a One-dimensional array

```
int[] array = new int[5];
```

Answer (score 1):

`int[][] a = new int[x][y]` is a shorthand for a loop that creates `x` arrays of size `y`:

```
int[][] a = new int[x][];
for (int i = 0; i < x; i++)
  a[i] = new int[y];
```

When `x` is zero then `y` is irrelevant since no array of size `y` is ever created. In fact in the general case there's no reason why the `x` arrays need to be the same size, or even exist, as any of the elements of a could just be `null` rather than an `int` array.

Answer (score 0):

```
int[][] a = new int[0][5];
```

you are trying to make zero sized array, remember in a 2D array `first []` represents the `size` of the `array`.

Example:

```
int[][] a = new int[2][4];    
a = {(1,2,3,4}, {5,6,7,8}}
System.out.println(a.length);// would return `2`
```

Comment: Saying that the first bracket initiates the size of the 2D array is kind of right but also kind of confusing.

Comment: If you say _"number of arrays"_ for example, that's less ambiguous. It's confusing since there are many arrays you could be referring to, but what you mean is the outer array. It could also be described as rows and columns, but that's more of an abstraction.